# Using exec to define a variable, raises an NameError when referencing it

Tags: python, exec

I'm now running an error (first off I already know that using `exec` isn't the best option but I'd rather not get into that right now) about a variable being undefined when referencing it. Which I find very strange considering it was working perfectly fine when I was using `exec(f'oneMileMark.append(entry{i}.get())')` (it was already a float at this point) before I added the ability to use the standard time format (1:36).

```py
for i in range(numOfRunners):
    if i%4 == 0: # used to distinguish between a runner's name and different times
        exec(f'time = entry{i}.get()') # gets the value of entry{i} and saves it as time
        minutes,seconds=time.split(':') # splits time into mins and secs
        newTime=float(minutes) + float(seconds)/60 # combines the minutes and hours into one bariable
        oneMileMark.append(newTime) # adds newTime to a list
```

Which gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Me/Desktop/Computer Programming/Python 3.x/Assignments/Programming 2/8/9_15 Computing 5k Mile Splits/main.py", line 91, in <module>
    app = Application(root)
  File "/Users/Me/Desktop/Computer Programming/Python 3.x/Assignments/Programming 2/8/9_15 Computing 5k Mile Splits/main.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.get_runner_data()
  File "/Users/Me/Desktop/Computer Programming/Python 3.x/Assignments/Programming 2/8/9_15 Computing 5k Mile Splits/main.py", line 53, in get_runner_data
    hours,minutes=time.split(':')
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your traceback and [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63940984/), you are using [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#index-1) within a method of a class like so:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        exec('x = "Hello World"')
        print(x)
```

When `exec` is executed within a function definition without a parameter for `globals`, any variables it creates is assigned to a new, temporary namespace, which cannot be accessed. Essentially, your `time` variable was made in an inner scope (which gets thrown away after exec finishes), and so you cannot access it outside of that scope.

```
>>> Foo().bar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ... 
  File "..\main.py", line 4, in bar
    print(x)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Why your previous exec() used to work before is because it only accessed `oneMileMark` and mutated the list with `.append()`, and didn't try to assign something new to the variable.

To solve this, you can use `eval` instead of `exec` so you can evaluate the expression while keeping your variable assignment remaining in the same scope:

```
for i in range(numOfRunners):
    if i%4 == 0:
        time_ = eval(f'entry{i}.get()')
        minutes,seconds=time_.split(':')
        ...
```

Note: If you were to use `exec` in the module level (outside of function or class definitions), any variable assignments will work on the global namespace:

```
>>> exec('x = "Hello World"')
>>> x
'Hello World'
```